# Display placeholder above select dropdown

Tags: jquery

My input fields display the placeholder in the field until it's in focus, at which point the placeholder is displayed above the field so that it's purpose is still visible to the user whilst they are filling in the field.

I wanted to do the same thing for select fields so I duplicated the jQuery code used on the input field and changed it to select, like this:

```
$(function() {
  var onClass = "on";
  var showClass = "show";

  $("select").bind("checkval", function() {
    var label = $(this).prev("label");
    if (!label.hasClass("excludeLabel")) {
      if (this.value !== "" || label.hasClass(onClass)) {
        label.addClass(showClass);
      } else {
        label.removeClass(showClass);
      }
    }
  }).on("focus", function() {
    $(this).prev("label").addClass(onClass);
    $(this).trigger("checkval");
  }).on("blur", function() {
    $(this).prev("label").removeClass(onClass);
    $(this).trigger("checkval");
  }).trigger("checkval");
});
```

Whilst it does have the desired effect of displaying the placeholder above the select, if the user clicks outside the field without making a selection on the dropdown the placeholder text doesn't hide as it does on the input fields.

Js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w8xqukej/2/

I thought the .on("blur", function() would have triggered that happening as it does on the input fields. Why doesn't it?

To be clear, the label should only hide if NO OPTION has been chosen from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues in your current code which i have fixed and it working normally.

1. You were not calling the right classes on `focus`
2. Also `.bind` function is deprecated since `jQuery 3.0` - You need to use `.on` which works the same as bind
3. Instead of `blur` use [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) to be specific that about if the user did not selected anything.

Run Snippet below.

```js
// input function starts here
$(function() {
  var onClass = "on";
  var showClass = "show";

  $("input").on("checkval", function() {
    var label = $(this).prev("label");
    if (!label.hasClass("excludeLabel")) {
      if (this.value !== "" || label.hasClass(onClass)) {
        label.addClass(showClass);
      } else {
        label.removeClass(showClass);
      }
    }
  }).on("keyup", function() {
    $(this).trigger("checkval");
  }).on("focus", function() {
    $(this).prev("label").addClass(onClass);
    $(this).trigger("checkval");
  }).on("focusout", function() {
    $(this).prev("label").removeClass(onClass);
    $(this).trigger("checkval");
  }).trigger("checkval");
});

// input function duplicated abd changed to select
$(function() {
  var onClass = "on";
  var showClass = "show";

  $("select").on("checkval", function() {
    var label = $(this).prev("label");
    if (!label.hasClass("excludeLabel")) {
      if (this.value !== "" || label.hasClass(onClass)) {
        label.addClass(onClass);
      } else {
        label.removeClass(onClass);
      }
    }
  }).on("focus", function() {
    $(this).prev("label").addClass(showClass);
    $(this).trigger("checkval");
  }).on("focusout", function() {
    $(this).prev("label").removeClass(showClass);
    $(this).trigger("checkval");
  }).trigger("checkval");
});

// other functions required for jsfiddle
$(function() {
  $.each($('input, textarea'), function(index, value) {
    $(this).data('holder', $(this).attr('placeholder'));
  });

  $('input, textarea').focusin(function() {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
  });

  $('input, textarea').focusout(function() {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('holder'));
  });
})

$(function() {
  var businessLabel = {
    val1: 'Type of Business',
  };
  var businessSelect = $('#type_of_business');
  $.each(businessLabel, function(val, text) {
    businessSelect.prepend(
      $('<option disabled hidden selected></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
  });
})
```

```css
.col,
.col-1,
.col-md {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #8d8d8d;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #c3c3c3 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inherit !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: inherit !important;
  box-shadow: inherit !important;
}

.form-control,
.input-styling {
  height: 4.8rem;
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #1D3143;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.form-control:hover,
.input-styling:hover {
  border-color: #1D3143 !important;
}

.form-control:focus,
.input-styling:focus {
  border-color: #ced4da !important;
  border-bottom-color: #37B571 !important;
}

.form-control:active,
.input-styling:active {
  border-color: #37B571 !important;
}

input.form-control.form-control-lg.required+p {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

input.form-control.form-control-lg.required:focus+p {
  display: block;
  color: #de1e1e;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

label.on {
  color: #1a92cf;
}

label.show {
  top: -6px;
  left: 19px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="CreateAccount row form-group">

  <div class="col">
    <label for="company">Business Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" onchange="capitalize(this,1)" aria-describedby="required_hint" class="form-control form-control-lg required" placeholder="Business Name *" required />
    <p class="required_hint">Field is required *</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="CreateAccount row form-group">

  <div class="col">
    <label class="inputLabel business" for="business">Type of Business</label>
    <select name="type_of_business" id="type_of_business" class="form-control form-control-lg">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Please select a business type</option>
      <option value="Balloon Decoration">Balloon Decoration</option>
      <option value="Party Retail">Party Retail</option>
      <option value="Online Retail">Online Retail</option>
      <option value="Gifts">Gifts</option>
      <option value="Other Retail">Other Retail</option>
      <option value="Entertainer / Modeller">Entertainer / Modeller</option>
      <option value="Event Organizer">Event Organizer</option>
      <option value="Event Venue">Event Venue</option>
      <option value="Special Effects">Special Effects</option>
      <option value="Arts and Crafts">Arts and Crafts</option>
      <option value="Children's Play Centre">Children&#039;s Play Centre</option>
      <option value="Florist">Florist</option>
      <option value="Wedding Decorator / Organizer">Wedding Decorator / Organizer</option>
      <option value="Catering">Catering</option>
      <option value="Fancy Dress">Fancy Dress</option>
      <option value="Market Trader">Market Trader</option>
      <option value="Post Office">Post Office</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```